Basic MSI Installer with Custom action to invoke a cmd batch script
I am trying to create a basic MSI installer in Install shield which takes password and few other params from the dialog box and then from custom action calls one test.cmd file passing some params to it. But the executable .cmd file is not getting triggered. I can run the installer and it is creating the files under Program Files folder.


This is the batch script file which i have added in the installdir. I am new to InstallShield. Any help appreciated.
